# trying to use IRIS-NP (IrisInConfigurationSpace) to decompose my scene

Tags: drake

we set up a scene of 3 hc10 arms, and the collision meshes look like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbiN7.png). but we kept getting the error message: `RuntimeError: The seed point is in collision; geometry hc10_multiple_arms::Cylinder is in collision with geometry hc10_multiple_arms::Sphere_3`, not always Cylinder and Sphere_3, but always some geo types. We have also tried using geometry types other than spheres, such as boxes and cylinders, but the same error occured, at that time, the meshes look like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFxve.png).

we were using macOS Ventura, arm64, Drake v1.18.0, python3.11

Comment: It is possible that each individual robot is in self-collision with itself. I would suggest to give each collision geometry a distinct name, and then you will see which pair of geometry is in collision.